# How to get a data class value given another one in kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, data-class

im trying to get one value of a data class given another one, for example given the id it returns the timestamp.

```
@Entity(tableName = "messages")
data class Message(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "timestamp")
    var timestamp: Long = 0
) 
{
    fun detalles(): Pair<Long, Long> {


        return Pair(id, timestamp)
    }

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    var id: Long = 0
}
```

Here is my take at it:

```
fun borrarMensajesViejos(msg: Message) = scope.launch {
        val nowUnixtime = System.currentTimeMillis()
        var i = 0;
        
        Log.i(TAG, nowUnixtime.toString())
        while (i <= msg.id) {
           val msgDet = msg.detalles()
            Log.i(TAG, msgDet.toString())
            Log.i(TAG, msgDet.second.toString())
            if (msgDet.second <= nowUnixtime - 20000) {
                chatManager.deleteMessage(id = i.toLong())
                Log.i(TAG, "Se ha borrado el mensaje ${i.toString()}")
            }
            i++;
        }

    }
```

this is not working as intended as only deletes the messages when 20 secs have gone by since the last msg. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: `if (msgDet.second <= nowUnixtime - 20000)` means, do this if the value is at least 20000 ms ago. What do want the behavior to actually be? We need to know your expected behavior to be able to advise you on what to change. We also probably need to know what `msgDet` is, and what the `second` property is. It's weird that you're comparing something called `second` to millisecond units.

Comment: @Tenfour04 
I want it so i give an ID and i get the timestamp for that id, then compare it(the one that i got from the id) to the current timestamp.
Ex:
id 12 has a timestamp of 1665766567789, so i want all previous id to be deleted `if the timestamp is <=  current time stamp - 20 secs`, so i do the `while` and go from id 0 to id latest msg id , and i want it so when i give the id 0 it gives me the timestamp so i can compare it with current, and so on with id 1,2... till latest msg id

Comment: What is the point of `detalles()`? All it does is take the existing properties and wrap them in an object that hides their useful names.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, this is likely the cleanest approach. It takes the timestamp of the message you pass in, compares it, then deletes all previous messages.

```
@Entity(tableName = "messages")
data class Message(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "timestamp")
    var timestamp: Long = 0,
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    var id: Long = 0,
)

fun borrarMensajesViejos(msg: Message) = scope.launch {
    val nowUnixtime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    if (msg.timestamp <= nowUnixtime - 20000) {
        for (i in 0..msg.id) {
            chatManager.deleteMessage(id = i)
        }
    }
}
```

If I'm not understanding correctly, then I would imagine you want a list or array of messages, maybe a map, and then call `filter` or `find` to find the messages you want to delete.

Comment: Is not quite it, each message has his timestamp and its id, I want to get the timestamp of a Message knowing its id, so I can only delete the messages that are 20 seconds old or more.